# How do I do to count rows in a sheets with filters? With a suppress lines

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I have a sheet with lots of columns, but when I filter and use

```
count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
```

It returns all the rows non Empty. Not only the rows I filtered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following which uses the SpecialCells() method to select only cells that are currently visible on screen (i.e. not filtered out).

```
count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
```

Comment: Tnks man, how do i do to count all cells unless if the cell is empty?